# functional update single value in q/kdb+

Tags: functional-programming, kdb, q-lang

```
t:([] col1:`aa`bb`cc;col2:`aaa`bbb`ccc);  
field1:`col1;  
field2:`col2;  
v1:`aa;  
v2:`aaaa;
```

I want same result by functional update as

```
update col2:`aaaa from t where col1=`aa;
```

I tried

```
![t;enlist (=;field1;enlist v1);0b;(enlist field2)!(enlist v2)];
```

but it give me an error `'aaaa`

appreciate if some one can help.

Answer (score 4):

```
![t;enlist (=;field1;enlist v1);0b;(enlist field2)!(enlist enlist v2)]
```

Comment: If you want coverage of all functional forms: http://www.timestored.com/kdb-guides/functional-queries-dynamic-sql#functional-update

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [parse](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/parsetrees/#parse) function to convert the update expression to a parse tree from which you can easily read off the proper arguments for the functional update.

```
q)parse"update col2:`aaaa from t where col1=`aa"
!
`t
,,(=;`col1;,`aa)
0b
(,`col2)!,,`aaaa
```

Recall that unary `,` is `enlist`, so the functional form of your query would be

```
![t;enlist(=;`col1;enlist `aa);0b;(enlist `col2)!enlist enlist `aaaa]
```

or, using variable names,

```
![t;enlist(=;field1;enlist v1);0b;(enlist field2)!(enlist enlist v2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not in functional update form, but here's another way you can updated your table

```
 @[t; where t[`col1] =`aa; :; enlist[`col1]!enlist[`aaaa]]
```